# Deploy PHP webapp over https on Elastic Search

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, https, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my company it's our first time using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy webapps and we are having difficulties to make it work over https. The application is running in single node (we aren't using a load balancer) and is written with CodeIgniter 3 in PHP 8.0 running over the EB platform v3.3.10. Now we have an environment with it working over http, while we try make it work over https.

We are using Apache as proxy server and we have generated the configuration files as mentioned in the docs. But we keep receiving errors during the deployment:
[deployment error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLOZW.png)

To simplify things we started trying to deploy a simple "hello world" app and make it work over https, but we keep failing... we don't know what we are failing at, what we are doing wrong...

The config files that we have made are the following ones.

**https-instance-single.config**

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

And **https-instance.config**

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
        SSLSessionTickets     Off
        
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early
      </VirtualHost>
  
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      My certificate
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      My private key
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The "funny" thing is that if we change *mod24_ssl* for just *mod_ssl*, it doesn't produce an error while deploying it, but still it doesn't work and doesn't expose the 443 port. We have checked it with telnet and it's closed.

We have checked in the security group that HTTP and HTTPS inbound traffic is enabled.

We suppose that we are not the first ones having this problem and it might be something that we have done wrong and hopefully something easy to make it work. So if someone reads this and knows what could it be, we really appreciate any help that you can provide.

Thank you

Comment: What is the version of your PHP EB platform that you are using?

Comment: The platform version is the 3.3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version `3.3.10` is based on Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), however all your settings are for AL1 which do not work in the new version.

To property setup your `httpd` in EB based on AL2 you have to use `.platform` folder, not `.ebextentions`. All details are in [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) under `Reverse proxy configuration` and `Configuring Apache HTTPD` sections.

Comment: Sorry for not answering before... Thanks for your response it helped a lot. We got it to work with NGINX, so we changed the proxy server, but we couldn't make it work with Apache. I'll keep testing by my own to know what I was doing wrong, but it's all working fine, so thank you.